# Jacobian and local invertibility of function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative, inverse-function-theorem

Following is a question in the text book:

Show by an example that the condition that the Jacobian vanishes at a point is not necessary for a function to be locally invertible at that point..... and the answer given is  f : R$^2$- R$^2$ f(x,y) = (x$^3$, y$^3$)

I am a bit confused by the question itself because my understanding is that  for local invertibility we check that Jacobian  is not zero....also for f(x,y) = (x$^3$, y$^3$), J works out to 9x$^2$y$^2$. So dont we say that this function is not invertible at either x=0 or y=0 since J at these values becomes 0? I am unable to understand the solution given in the textbook

I request help to understand this problem and the given solution

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typo in the text. It should say "...the condition that the Jacobian does not vanish...".

$f(x,y)=(x^3,y^3)$ is invertible. Its inverse is $f^{-1}(x,y)=(\sqrt[3]{x},\sqrt[3]{y})$. What happens is that the inverse is not differentiable.

Comment: Thank you very much. It does make sense if it reads "Jacobian does not vanish" and it appears a typo in textbook.. and that was the reason I was confused. But I have still not understood how the example in the textbook shows that Jacobian does not vanish is not a necessary for function to be locally invertible. May I request you to please amplify the explanation given by you? Can you please give another example to make it clear?

Comment: To show that non vanishing of the Jacobian is not a necessary condition for local invertibility, all you have to do is to exhibit a function that is invertible and whose Jacobian vanishes at some point; $f(x,y)=(x^3,y^3)$ is such an example. Another example (essentially the same): $f(x,y)=(y^5,x^7)$.